# How to select an element using mouse drag in ember?

Tags: ember.js

[image: SCREEN SHOT]I have my template like this,

```
<div>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
        {{#view "selection" model=item}}
          <div class="child_div">{{item.name}}</div> 
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

In my js, I am using a view for select an clicked element like,

Model:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [{'is_active':false, 'name':'One'}, {'is_active':false, 'name':'Two'}, {'is_active':false, 'name':'Three'}, {'is_active':false, 'name':'Four'},{'is_active':false, 'name':'Five'}];
    } 
});
```

Selection View:

```
App.SelectionView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: ["isActive"],
    isActive: Ember.computed.alias('model.is_active'), // No I18N
    click: function (){
        var self = this; self.get("controller").setEach("is_active", false); // No I18N
        self.toggleProperty("isActive"); // No I18N
    }
});
```

Here, I am selecting that div's in click event. I need to select them when I do use mouse drag.

How do I do that using mouse drag selection? Kindly help me out of that.

DEMO: [JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dacawo/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `draggable` attribute to your view and use the `dragStart` event.

```
attributeBindings : [ 'draggable' ],
draggable         : 'true',
dragStart: function(event) {
  var self = this; 
  self.get("controller").setEach("is_active", false); // No I18N
  self.toggleProperty("isActive");
}
```

**[Here is working demo.](http://jsbin.com/cogoci/1/edit?html,js,output)**

[**Here is a good article from Lauren Tan on drag n drop in Ember.**](https://medium.com/delightful-ui-for-ember-apps/ember-js-and-html5-drag-and-drop-fa5dfe478a9a)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have attached the screenshot that what I exactly want. Give a look at that screenshot and let me know the further way.

Comment: Oh i understood ur questions wrong. Well the easiest way is to wrap jquery UI selectable widget into a component and use that. Or you may need to reverse engineer that code to implement it.